# How to filter a connection in python?

Tags: python, sockets, ip, ports

I wrote a code to open a socket and then accept the socket and connect it. 
What is the problem? I want to filter the incoming connection ip.
So I wrote a "if" statement for the connecting ip but it wont work. 
Looking forward for your help!

```
#!/usr/bin/python           

import socket               

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket 
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345                # opening a port
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                # Now wait for client connection.
c, addr = s.accept()       # accept the client
c.send('waiting for connection...')  
if '192' in addr:  #---->This is what does not work. 
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   print 'accepted'
else:
   c.close() 
   print 'blocked.'
   print '{0} tried to connect'.format(addr)
print 'a connection was request from', addr
raw_input("Press enter to continue: ")
```

Comment: What actually happens?

Comment: Are you sure `addr` is a string containing the IP? maybe it is a tuple that contains the couple `(address,port)`

Answer (score 1):

As we can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454675/whats-the-return-value-of-socket-accept-in-python), addr that you get from s.accept() is a tuple containing the ip adress and the port. To check the ip adress use addr[0]

```
>>> ip='192.168.1.1'
>>> '192' in ip
True
>>> addr=(ip, 2424)
>>> '192' in addr
False
>>> '192' in addr[0]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

'addr' in the above code is a tuple containing the IP address and port number of the far end, it will look something like this:

```
('127.0.0.1', 48223)
```

For the above:

```
>>> '127' in addr
False
>>> '127' in addr[0]
True
```

Hopefully this gives you enough to modify the code.