# Why and how am i supposed to use socket.accept() in python?

Tags: java, python, sockets

This `accept()` method return a tuple with a new socket and an address but why do i need a new socket if i already have one, so why don't use it?

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print 'connected:', addr

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
   conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

ps: When i program sockets in Java, i don't really have this kind of *accepting* stuff and i only need one socket per client and one per server, which makes sense.

Comment: Java does this exactly the same way. Both are simple wrappers over the standard Socket API.

Comment: You should read a good socket tutorial. It will clear this and many other things up. Try https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Comment: Look at the [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) class. Also for Python see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454675/whats-the-return-value-of-socket-accept-in-python

Comment: This is quite a low level Api. You probably worked at a higher level in Java.  You can in Python too with a library, like [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you haven't implemented TCP in Java before.

The example you are providing with, uses a default `AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM` which *by default* is TCP:

> socket.socket([family[, type[, proto]]])
>   Create a new socket using the given address family, socket type and protocol number. The address family should be AF_INET (the default), AF_INET6 or AF_UNIX. The socket type should be SOCK_STREAM (the default), SOCK_DGRAM or perhaps one of the other SOCK_ constants. The protocol number is usually zero and may be omitted in that case.

If you were implemented `SOCK_DGRAM` which is UDP, you wouldn't need to be using `sock.accept()`

Answer (score 2):

You have one listening socket active while the server is running and one new connected socket for each accepted connection which is active until the connection is closed.