# defining two variables with one method

Tags: python-sockets

hi i'm very new to python.I was watching a socket programming video and it told me to write a code like this.

```
conn ,address = s.accept()
```

i'm confused because it defined two variables with one method at the same time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the return value of Socket.accept() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454675/whats-the-return-value-of-socket-accept-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because that method returns two variables. a method or function can return basically any amount of variables. for example:

```
def test_func(a):
    b = a * 2
    c = a * 3
    return b, c
```

i am returning b and c in the last line of the function. now to call the function:

```
x, y = test_func(20)
```

and if you print x and y, you'll get:

`40 60`